# How to keep bootstrap carousel paused until it enters in the viewport?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

EDIT: *reason for this request. This edit has been added when the solution has been found for the sake of describing my needs. I had a Carousel that showed a logical sequence step 1, step 2, step 3.. That carousel is not a top of page, so I want it to stay stopped / paused until the user sees it and when it will see it, as first, I want the user to see the first slide, step 1. Nevertheless, some users (and they are not few, believe me) don't know about carousels and sliders, so I don't wanna miss their view on the subsequent slides. This is the reason for what follow.*

I'm wondering about this

I have a bootstrap 3.1 carousel that is **not** at top of the home page.

Instead you "reach it" when scrolling down some "bootstrap' rows".

Well I'd like it to keep the carousel stopped / paused until the user will scroll the page down to where the carousel is placed (let's say the carousel height is 500 pixel, when at least the first top 150 pixels are entered in the viewable area)

when those 150 pixel have been scrolled in, the pause / stop should turn to "play" and so, if the pause between each slide is 5000 msec, after 5000 msec the next slide should turn.

According with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459861/reset-twiiter-bootstrap-carousel-when-scrolls-of-page) it is matter of javascript but it is not what I'm seeking for also excuse me but currently I'm not so strong with javascript and jquery, so thank you for any hint with some explanation.

EDIT 01
[This script](http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-test-if-element-is-in-viewport-visible-on-screen) looks to be the correct and also a great solution :-), especially reading the comments at bottom of that page, but as stated above, I miss the knowledge to properly take advantage of it, thank you for any hint.

Comment: Hello! Any kind help about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the long path, self answered myself.

I've tried several plugins, but they were not effective or either they were breaking the Carousel engine.

Researching so much, finally I've landed on this jQuery plugin
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Determine-If-An-Element-Is-In-the-Viewport-Viewport-Checker.html

It works pretty fine, straight and as expected and there is a bonus included: the offset I was seeking for!!! (yeeeh!)

Pretty easy to implement

```
<script src="viewportchecker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel('pause'); /** load page with carousel paused

    $('.carousel').viewportChecker({
        offset: 200,                  /** wait for the first 200 pixel of the element 
                                          to enter in the viewport
        callbackFunction: function(elem){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.carousel').carousel(''); /** remove pause
            },500);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

"thank you" to myself :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method using [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API); it will fail silently for IE and other unsupported browsers.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  if (IntersectionObserver === undefined) return;
    const carousels = $(".carousel");
    if (carousels.length === 0) return;
    const RATIO = 0;
    // You can set a intersection percentage, such as 0.25 for 25% visible, but 
    // if you want pixels, I'm using `rootMargin` in the options below
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            jQuery(entry.target).carousel(entry.intersectionRatio < RATIO ? 'pause' : 'cycle');
        });
    }, {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: '-150px 0px', // 150px visible on top or bottom of viewport
            threshold: RATIO
        });
    carousels.each(function () {
        observer.observe(this);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer for the most performance instead running a check thousands of times on scrolling, just add your polify or don't cause IE is finally gone next year and everyone will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would also help the problem when the viewport cuts the carousel in half.   ie: With a carousel at the top of the page and you scroll down, forcing the top of browser window to show only the bottom half of carousel.

Currently, when the carousel cycles, the carousel images load to the top of the viewport, not the top of the carousel container.

When you scroll back up, the carousel only displays half the image and the top half is grey.  This is very annoying.  Will try this to see if it fixes.